# discord python - counting messages from a week and save them

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, discord.py

I have a question, but can't find an answer. I want to count messages, but only messages from Monday to Sunday and resets the counter to zero at 12 AM in german time.

I know that this works for counting messages:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(721833279711477941)
count = 0
async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
   count += 1
await channel.send(f"{count} messages in this channel")
```

I know how I can count channel messages, but I don't know how I can count all messages, from the week, saves the counted messages, and make it comfortable for the bot, so he doesn't need much time to count it.

And obviously, the bot should not take a while to count the messages. I don't want that. So I got the idea to save all counted messages inside a database and just count forward at every message. But the bot should still count every message from the week in a specific channel (maybe he do that just one time, to store it in the database).

I need this feature for learning how that can work in python and want to use a {count} placeholder for a discord channel.
I hope I explained it well and understandable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **datetime** library to make some easy functions to calculate when was last *monday* and next *sunday*, as you want to calculate the amount of messages within that time, some code that could work is the following:

```
def last_monday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    monday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
    return monday


def next_sunday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    sunday = today + datetime.timedelta((6-today.weekday()) % 7)
    return sunday
```

Those functions calculate the previous monday or the next sunday taking as reference **today** and adding or substracting the necessary amount of days. The returned value is in datetime accepted format.

Then in your **discord.py** code you can simply use the **before** and **after** within the call to the `channel.history` to tell Discord the range of time where to look for those messages. Using the functions that I posted above, your discord function should have something along these lines:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(721833279711477941)
messages = channel.history(limit=None, before=next_sunday(), after=last_monday()).flatten()
count = len(messages)
await channel.send(f"{count} messages in this channel")
```

Comment: Don't must I save the counted message in a database or something? Can the bot count those messages fast?

Comment: If you only want to **count** them, there is no need to store anything in a database, that would actually take a way longer time. This method should be fast enough for most discord servers.

Comment: and resets the counter itself at 00:00 at week end?

Comment: It should reset on Sunday at 00:00 indeed.

Comment: I get the error `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'id'
` for the line `async for message in channel.history(limit=None, before=next_sunday(), after=last_monday()):`.

Comment: I have edited the code, try this one now. It was using the wrong datetime.datetime class.

Comment: I added it now and the counted messages stucks at zero.

Comment: do you know a fix for that?

Comment: Make sure you and the bot have permissions to see the message history and the messages [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents) are enabled.

Comment: I have that all. the bot has admin perms.

Comment: I have edited the code to try avoid doing a for loop, I have tested it myself and this code works as well, try to use this one.

Comment: now i get `TypeError: object of type 'coroutine' has no len()` for `count = len(messages)`.

Comment: My bad, missing an `await` to call channel.history.